# VirtualBox 6.0.12 Extension Package: URL not found

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, installation, uninstall

Host system: Ubuntu 18.04

Just an hour ago I did an `apt-get update/upgrade` and installed VirtualBox **6.0.12 r133076**.

When starting VirtualBox, it wants to upgrade the extension package.

That fails with the message:

> The network operation failed with the following error: During network request: Url not found on the server.

How can I manage that?

As 6.0.12 is brand new, is it a server issue, which will be fixed server-side, so should I do nothing and wait and try it again later or downgrade / rollback to 6.0.10?

If a rollback is needed, how can I do it with the terminal in a safe manner, so that I do not delete anything from my current machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by copying the url that virtualbox shows and pasting it to a browser web address, then selecting virtualbox to open it and allowing the upgrade to proceed.

Comment: I have the same error, but I don't understand, "copying the url that virtualbox shows…" Mine doesn't show any URL to copy. There's only the error message as per the OP. Please would you help? **EDIT:** I figured it out. I had to cancel the operation and try again, and then it showed the URL.